# Confused by MSDN "recommended way of handling errors" in COM

Tags: error-handling, com, msdn

I have been reading the MSDN dev guide to COM.  However the code on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is confusing. Reproducing here:

> The following code sample shows the recommended way of handling unknown errors:

```
HRESULT hr; 
hr = xxMethod(); 

switch (GetScode(hr))  
{ 
    case NOERROR: 
      // Method returned success. 
      break; 

    case x1: 
      // Handle error x1 here.
      break; 

    case x2: 
      // Handle error x2 here.
      break; 

    case E_UNEXPECTED: 
    default: 
      // Handle unexpected errors here. 
      break; 
}
```

The `GetScode` function doesn't seem to be defined, nor is `NOERROR`, and searching MSDN didn't help. A web search indicated that `GetScode` is a macro that converts HRESULT to SCODE, however those are both 32-bit ints so I'm not sure what it is for.

It was suggested that it is a historical artifact that does nothing on 32-bit systems, but on 16-bit systems it converts `hr` to a 16-bit int. However, if that is true, then I do not see how `E_UNEXPECTED` would be matched, since that is `0x8000FFFF`. Also, it's unclear whether `x1` and `x2` are meant to be `0x800.....` values, or some sort of truncated version.

Finally, this code treats all-but-one of the success values as errors. Other pages on the same MSDN guide say that `SUCCEEDED(hr)` or `FAILED(hr)` should be used to determine between a success or failure.

So, is this code sample *really* the "recommended way" or is this some sort of documentation blunder?

Comment: That must be a pretty old document. `GetScode` is a macro that has *long* been obsolete. It used to be the recommended way, but is no longer.

Answer (score 1):

This is (pretty) old stuff. The `winerror.h` file in the SDK says this:

```
////////////////////////////////////
//                                //
//     COM Error Codes            //
//                                //
////////////////////////////////////


//
// The return value of COM functions and methods is an HRESULT.
// This is not a handle to anything, but is merely a 32-bit value
// with several fields encoded in the value. The parts of an
// HRESULT are shown below.
//
// Many of the macros and functions below were orginally defined to
// operate on SCODEs. SCODEs are no longer used. The macros are
// still present for compatibility and easy porting of Win16 code.
// Newly written code should use the HRESULT macros and functions.
//
```

I think it's pretty clear. I would trust the SDK first, and the doc after that.

We can see SCODE is consistently defined like this in `WTypesbase.h` (in recent SDKs, in older SDKs, I think it was in another file):

```
typedef LONG SCODE;
```

So it's really a 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

The text is correct; one *should* be wary of blindly returning failure codes from internal functions, particularly if your code uses a [facility code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) defined elsewhere in the system.

Specifically, at the COM interface function level, you *should* ensure that the error codes you're returning are meaningful *for your interface*, and you should remap errors that originate from inside the function to meaningful error codes.

Practically speaking, however, nobody does this, which is why you see bizarre and un-actionable error dialogs like "Unexpected error".